# Windows WDF Driver Power States

Tags: windows, driver, wdf

I'm working with **WDF**. Im reading a driver sample but cannot infer the semantic meaning of:
 - *WdfPowerDeviceD0*
 - *WdfPowerDeviceD1*
 - *WdfPowerDeviceD2*
 - *WdfPowerDeviceD3*
 - *WdfPowerDeviceD3Final*.

Would appreciate any help on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

These are device specific power states. Check ACPI 6.0 spec's section titled "2.3 Device Power State Definitions" Which sample are you looking at ?

Comment: Im looking at the PCMIA Smart Card Example. Getting a wiff at some Driver Code, eventually I'll have to develop one, but it is quite hard to straighten out.